# Access to a network server without port forwarding

Tags: networking, routing, socket

I have a network with the following structure.

[image]

The server in PC2 is simple socket server TCP in 8080 port.

I need to access to PC2 from other external network by socket client. This socket client knows the public IP (85.xxx.xxx.x), the private IP (192.168.0.21) and the port.

How I can access PC2 without port forwarding on the router?

If possible, I would like to have a reference in any programming language of this case.

[Additional info](https://mega.co.nz/#!iZRgiaTB!HHJqiLnON8JF_HpGqrLSeSQMVVJ7keXLtV-0i_ykl5I)

Comment: What do you mean by "If possible, I would like to have a reference in any programming language of this case."?

Comment: If there was a way to do what I want. I would like to see an example of a socket client with a programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **How I can access PC2 without port forwarding on the router?**

Assuming a NAT router (which is almost certain given a 192.168.0.0/24 internal network), you can't do this without port-forwarding at the router. Or something very similar.

For example if you can SSH to the router and then to the server you could use SSH tunelling (which is a form of port-forwarding).

You could also have PC2 SSH to a public server and make available a tunelled endpoint there. (you might need something like netcat or socat to assist with this)

In general, port-forwarding at the router is the way to go.

---

### Protocols for NAT traversal

There are ways to enable this sort of communication without manual configuration of port-forwarding but they usually rely on router support and/or an external connection broker.

**General**

- [UDP Hole punching](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/udp-hole-punching/) - very clear explanation
- [Hole Punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking))
- [NAT Traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal)

**Specific**

- [IGDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Gateway_Device_Protocol).
- [STUN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Traversal_Utilities_for_NAT)
- [ICE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Connectivity_Establishment)
- [NAT-PMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_Port_Mapping_Protocol)
- [PCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_Control_Protocol)
- [UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play)

---

> **I would like to have a reference in any programming language of this case**

If you are writing the software at both ends there are probably many examples you can follow.

For example, see

- [Java UDP hole punching example - connecting through firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656198/java-udp-hole-punching-example-connecting-through-firewall)
- [Implementing a TCP Hole Punching NAT Traversal 
  Solution](http://yen.cs.stir.ac.uk/courses/ITNP98/PastDissertations/2009-2010/Dissertations/HaddadZ.pdf)

Comment: This question comes because I used on my Android device an application that establishes a socket TCP server when the device is connected through Wi-Fi (Tested with Nmap), and I can access with a client on another device of another network without any redirection ports.

Comment: @SdevDavid: And does that app use an external server that mediates the connection?

Comment: Yes, it has a server to identify clients and servers, but communication between (Android client-Android server) is directly between two Android devices.

Comment: For more information, this app does is, turn your device in an IP camera server and lets you connect with a client without port forwarding. And I'd like to know how it does.

Comment: @SevDavid: To find out what your WiFi IP-camera does, you'd need an 802.11 sniffer. Or plug it into an intermediary Ethernet switch that has port-mirroring (or use a hub). But see IGDP in updated answer.

Comment: I have looked at the router's manual, and do not put it anywhere that supports IGDP. 
What I will do is sniff all traffic from the Wi-Fi network with a Wi-Fi card in a PC, use the Wi-Fi password and use wireshark to see what it does. When I do that, I will comment here which is the origin and destination of the frames.

Comment: I have done the test with the server connected to Wifi and clinet by 3G. I search frames by TCP.port == 8014 in wireshark. I found that all communications are direct between the two devices, no server between them.

Comment: @SdevDavid: Searching by the listening port on the Android device means you don't see any set-up traffic between device and router (or external service) prior to the establishment of an inbound TCP connection.

Comment: I tried to understand the connection setup but I not have enough knowledge to understand. I edited the first post with the frames captured in additional info if you can help me.

Comment: You really linked to the Wikipedia page for "Hole punch"? (as in hole punch for a 3 ring binder kinda hole punch). Not sure thats relevant, lol.

Comment: @Justin: Thanks. Either I messed up 4 years ago or Wikipedia changed the disambiguation for the term. I'd like to think it's them, but it's probably me.

Comment: @Justin: Aha! It was Wikipedia pulling the rug from under me! https://web.archive.org/web/20140606023215/http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching